# Dynamically create a function with default parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

One of the features introduced by ECMAScript 6 is the ability to indicate default values for unspecified parameters in JavaScript, e.g.

```
function foo(a = 2, b = 3) {
    return a * b;
}

console.log(foo());   // 6
console.log(foo(5));  // 15
```

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to use default parameters also for functions created dynamically with the `Function` constructor, like this:

```
new Function('a = 2', 'b = 3', 'return a * b;');
```

Firefox 39 seems to already support default parameters ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters#Browser_compatibility)), but the line above is rejected as a syntax error.

Comment: Hmmm, why do you need a string argument instead of just `a =2`? It would be slightly more difficult to use, isn't it?

Comment: This seems to be related to [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755821) bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I'm wondering if it's possible to use default parameters also for functions created dynamically with the Function constructor

Yes, according to [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createdynamicfunction) this is possible. The parameter arguments are concatenated as always and then parsed according to the `FormalParameters` production, which includes default values.

> Firefox 39 seems to already support default parameters, but the line above is rejected as a syntax error.

Well, that's a bug :-) (probably [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755821))
You should be able to work around it by using

```
var fn = Function('return function(a = 2, b = 3) { return a * b; }')();
```

Answer (score 0):

As `new Function` is a form of eval anyway you could use the following code for that task:

```
eval('function bar (a = 2, b = 3) { return a * b; }');
```

Comment: Probably because it's a function declaration, so `eval` will return undefined. You should use a function expression instead.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that is supposed to work - some one else will have to tell you - but if it continues to be a problem, why not use eval()?

Something in the lines on this should be legal:

```
var fct1 = eval("(function foo(a = 2, b = 3) { return a * b; })")
```